# Let Fa be a $ \mathcal L_1^{=} $ - closed formula and $ \Delta$ = { $\forall y(Fy \to Gy), \lnot Ga$} a set of $ \mathcal L_1^{=} $ ...

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

Let Fa be a $ \mathcal L_1^{=} $ - closed formula and $ \Delta$ = { $\forall x(Fx \to Gx), \lnot Ga$} a set of $ \mathcal L_1^{=} $ - closed formulas, where F and G are predicate symbols and $\mathbf a$ is an constant. According to the classic semantics, Fa is the semantic consequence of $\Delta $ ie $ \Delta \vDash$ Fa?

What have I done so far

By contradiction

Suppose $ \Delta $ is not a semantic consequence of Fa. Then there is B (Fa) = false,. By definition B ($ \forall x (Fx \to Gx) $) = true and B ($ \lnot $ Ga) = true. But if B ($ \forall (Fi \to Gi) $) = T, this implies that B ($ \forall (Fa \to Ga) $)= V then or B (Fa) = F or B (Ga) = V,  but by the hypothesis B (Fa) = F, so B (Ga) needs to be either T or F, as we assume that B ($ \lnot $ Ga) = T. No contradiction.

Comment: Not very clear... But the first part (the attempted contradiction) is fine. We may have $Fa$ False and $Ga$ False. Thus $Fa \to Ga$ is True and this means that we have an interpretation where both premises are True and the conclusion is False, i,e, the conclusion is not a consequence of the premises.

Comment: Also you are trying to show whether or not *"$Fa$ is a semantic consequence of $\Delta$"*.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I don't know if I got it right. Let me see if this is it, $ \forall (Fa \to Ga) $ = T then Fa = T and Ga = T is a valid option but how can we assume Fa = F this cannot happen?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Sorry, but I didn't get your point.

Comment: @Andre You have the phrase backwards.  $\Delta\models Fa$ is read "$\Delta$ semantically entails $Fa$", which is equivalent to "$Fa$ is a semantic consequence of $\Delta$".

Comment: @GrahamKemp Ahh now I understand thanks